# Why do interrupted processes show up in nvidia-smi?

Tags: nvidia, kill, gpu, interrupt

When ​I kill processes in terminal using `C-c` and run `nvidia-smi`, the process are still shown as "compute processes". These processes are no longer in the `top` resu​lts. I have to `kill -9` to clean them (or `pkill -9` if I don't have any running processes I care about).

Why do interrupted processes show up in nvidia-smi?

Example:

[image]

(I took the image from this [Quora question](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-kill-all-the-computer-processes-shown-in-nvidia-smi))